# Is it possible to use Ruby (not jRuby) frontend of the Selenium 2 (WebDriver) with HtmlUnit backend?

Tags: ruby, selenium, htmlunit, webdriver

I want to use WebDriver on a server-side, without any browser or gui. It is possible with HtmlUnitDriver in a Java bindigns for WebDriver. But I like ruby more than java. Can I solve my problem with ruby bindings or I must use java bindings?

Answer (score 2):

Since HtmlUnit is a Java library, you need Java at some point in your stack. If you want the tests to run on MRI, this can be done with the [the Selenium Remote server](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar) (and the [selenium-webdriver gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver)).

Instructions are [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Remote) on the Selenium wiki.

Comment: Yes, I know about the remote selenium server, and it's a one of the way to solve my problem. But I want to pack all in an one pure ruby module. Maybe anyone know about a Ruby binding for HtmlUnit or an Ruby alternative of the Java HtmlUnit.

Comment: You won't be using WebDriver then, but you could look at Akephalos: https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/akephalos

Comment: Akephalos is very interesting project, thanks for the link. But it's a driver for Capybara, not for Selenium. I can use Selenium or Akephalos from Capybara, but I can't use Akephalos from Selenium directly.